# Import a custom class in the test class in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have created a folder called database and a Java class called SleepNight in it. And the test class can't recognize SleepNight class, how can I fix this problem?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7TWd.png)

I search in google for a solution to solve my problem, but I didn't find one that solve my problem.

Comment: Try Invalidating caches by going to file and then restart Android Studio

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: I tested it in my project but my test class recognizes the database class in the main class, it must be something with android studio

Comment: Shaurya Goyal, thanks you for testing this, and for that information. I will check if there is a problem in my android studio that prevent the test class to work correctly.